# Add transition to back button in swift

Tags: ios, swift, uinavigationbar, back-button

HI guys im trying to add a nice smooth transition to my back button

im trying to do it with a transition function on a selector like the following

```
navigationItem.backBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(title: "", style: 
.plain, target: self, action: #selector(tran))
```

and the transition function is as follows

```
 @objc func tran() {
    let transition = CATransition()
    transition.duration = 0.5
    transition.type = kCATransitionPush
    transition.subtype = kCAGravityTop
    self.view.window?.layer.add(transition, forKey: kCATransition)
    print("test")
}
```

ive used the transition function on another view controller and works fine, just can not get it working on this navigation back button

anyone have a working way of doing this?

thanks

Comment: can you specify what happens and what is not happening?

Comment: Are you trying to add the transition to the viewController itself? Maybe this could help you: http://mathewsanders.com/animated-transitions-in-swift/